# Alternative spherical coordinate systems

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

For some specific reasons, I need to use an alternative spherical coordinate system defined as follows:

$x=R~{\rm cos}~\varphi~{\rm cos}~\vartheta, \\
y=R~{\rm sin}~\varphi, \\
z=-R~{\rm cos}~\varphi~{\rm sin}~\vartheta,$

where $R \ge 0$, $\vartheta \in [0, \pi)$, and $\varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$.

My question is whether there is a standard name for this coordinate system. If no, how would you call this system?

Comment: It is still a spherical coordinate system but with $z$ axis replaced by $y$ axis, and $\theta$ replaced by $-\theta$ (if you refer to the Earth, it is like counting longitude westwards instead of eastwards from the Greenwich meridian)

Comment: Tip: Instead of `{\rm cos}~\varphi`, you can simply write `\cos\varphi`.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. Meanwhile I found some hints on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system (under point "Conventions"). Can my coordinate system be defined with the easting (E), northing (N), upwardness (U) terms?

Comment: I have had a look at your reference. Honestly, I didn't know these terms. They may apply to your change $\theta \to - \theta$ but they will not account for the fact that your "pole" (still with comparison with the Earth), instead of being the North pole, is in a point like Singapore...

Comment: GIS SE refers to northings and eastings, e.g. [Why do some coordinate systems define x axis as northings and others as eastings?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99769/why-some-coordinate-systems-define-x-axis-as-northings-and-some-as-easting). I think @JeanMarie is correct, that you still have a spherical coordinate system, but it is using different conventions or maybe transformation. The GIS answers in the link describe why you might want to do that.

Comment: They exchanged the roles of $y$ and $z$ while leaving $x$ unchanged. But if you do this strictly, it changes from a normal RH coordinate system to a LH coordinate system, and apparently they didn't want that, so they also reversed the direction of $z$. But there is another difference between this and normal spherical coordinates. Usually, it is $\vartheta$ that goes full circle, and $\varphi$ only sweeps out a half circle. But for some reason, they've reversed that here.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for your comment. Do you know how to convert $(x,y,z)$ to $(R,\vartheta,\varphi)$ in this coordinate system: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192628/how-to-determine-the-angles-of-a-particular-point-in-a-special-spherical-coordin?noredirect=1#comment8695796_4192628?