# How to determine the angles of a particular point in a special spherical coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, transformation, spherical-coordinates

Consider a point $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ whose coordinates are defined in the following way:

$x=R\cos\varphi\cos\vartheta, \\
y=R\sin\varphi, \\
z=-R\cos\varphi\sin\vartheta,$

where $R \ge 0$, $\vartheta \in [0, \pi)$, and $\varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$.

My goal is to express $(R,\vartheta,\varphi)$ from $(x,y,z)$. Could you please help me how to determine $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ with their proper phase in $[0,\pi)$ and $[0,2\pi)$, respectively?

Comment: You can look at [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), @TobiR

Comment: There is no such coordinate system under your link.

Comment: @TobiR but yes.

Comment: @NN2 Under what point?

Comment: One esoteric but clean way (often used in computer graphics) is to create the pure quaternion (0,x,y,z) and then use the standard formula for converting a quaternion to a rotation matrix.

Comment: I don't know how you can't see what you are seeking in the link. You should see the link again.

Comment: @NN2 Do you mean "Cartesian coordinates" of "Coordinate system conversions"? Here are the formulas for the "standard" spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$R = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$
If $R = 0$ then set $\varphi = \vartheta = 0$.

Let $\vartheta' = \text{atan2}(x, -z)$, and let $\varphi' = \text{atan2}(\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}, y)$. I will assume your `atan2` function returns angles in $[0,2\pi)$ and has the horizontal coordinate first, vertical coordinate second (check - there are different conventions). Because the first coordinate is $\ge 0$, either $\varphi' \in \left[0, \frac \pi 2\right]$ or $\varphi' \in \left[\frac {3\pi} 2, 2\pi\right)$.

- If $\vartheta' < \pi$, then set $\vartheta = \vartheta', \varphi = \varphi'$.
- If $\vartheta' \ge\pi$, then set $\vartheta = \vartheta' - \pi$.

  - If $\varphi' \in \left[0, \frac \pi 2\right]$, set $\varphi = \pi - \varphi'$
  - If $\varphi' \in \left[\frac {3\pi} 2, 2\pi\right)$, set $\varphi = 3\pi - \varphi'$

If `atan2` returns angles in $[-\pi, \pi)$,

- If $\vartheta' \ge 0$, then set $\vartheta = \vartheta'$.

  - If $\varphi' \ge 0$, set $\varphi = \varphi'$.
  - If $\varphi' < 0$, set $\varphi = 2\pi + \varphi'$
- If $\vartheta' < 0$, then set $\vartheta = \vartheta' + \pi$ and $\varphi = \pi - \varphi'$.

Comment: Thank you very much! My `atan2` function returns angles in $[-\pi,\pi)$. How do the formulas change in this case? Or I should just simply add $+\pi$ to $\vartheta'$ and $\varphi'$?

Comment: I remarked earlier that $\varphi'$ cannot fall in that range, because $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2} \ge 0$. I am adding the conditions for your atan2 function. Note in this case $\varphi'$ will be between $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ for the same reason.

Comment: OK, thanks. Meanwhile I realized that you mentioned the possible ranges before the itemized list.

Comment: Also thanks for the update. I am extremely greatful to you for presenting these formulas. Now I am writing a subroutine calculating them. :)

Comment: Just a quick question: what if (1) $z=0$ or (2) $y=0$?

Comment: `atan2` has no problem handling cases where one of the coordinates is $0$. That is part of why it is a standard computer function. If you are forced to work with $\text{atan}(u/v)$ instead, then care must be taken (and more than just for the $v=0$ case, as computation error gets out of hand before then). If $y = 0$, then $\varphi = 0$ or $\varphi = \pi$, depending on the values of $x, z$.

Comment: For $(x,y,z)=(2,0,0)$ I got $\vartheta=\varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I would expect $0$ for both angles. My Fortran code returned atan2$(x,-z)=$atan2$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Probably you have an `atan2` function that expects the vertical coordinate first, and horizontal second in contravention to long established mathematical standards. It drives me nuts when some wonky programmer does things like this! Try reversing the order of the coordinates in them.

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem for $(x,y,z) = (2,0,0)$. However, I still have an issue with $(x,y,z)=(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2, 0)$. For this point, I obtain $\vartheta = 0$ and $\varphi \approx 0.1958 \pi$, while the correct angles should be $\vartheta = 0$ and $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Check what values are going into the $\varphi'$ atan calculation. It should be $\text{atan2}(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$, since $\sqrt{(\sqrt 2)^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt 2$. And $\text{atan2}(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2) = \frac \pi 4$.

Comment: It's my fault, sorry. I accidentally wrote $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ instead of $\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$. Furthermore, conversion between degrees and radians was made only for the first `if` block... Now everything works for all $\vartheta = 0, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2}, ... $ and $\varphi= 0, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2}, ... $ and also for the multiples of  $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Thank you very much for you kind assistance!